NFC Reader is not receiving any data if I tap on my demo smart tap enabled generic pass
I am trying to build a demo generic pass with smart tap functionality but when I am tapping on my VTAP 50 DOT Origin NFC reader I am not getting any kind of data.
Here is my nfc code:
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport');
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline');

// Replace with your actual serial port
const portName = '/dev/tty.usbmodem21101';  // on Windows, this might be 'COM3' or similar

const port = new SerialPort({ path: portName,
    baudRate: 9600,
    lock: false});
const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));

async function listSerialPorts() {
    try {
        const ports = await SerialPort.list()
        console.log('Available ports:')
        ports.forEach(port => {
            console.log(`- ${port.path}\t${port.manufacturer || 'Unknown manufacturer'}`)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error listing ports:', err)
    }
}
listSerialPorts();

port.on('open', () => {
    console.log('Serial port opened');
});

parser.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Received data:', data);
    processNFCData(data);
});

port.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err.message);
});

function processNFCData(data) {

    if (data.startsWith('Testing data')) {
        console.log('NFC tag detected!');
        console.log('Card data:', data);
    }
}

And my output is showing Dot Origin as manufacturer after calling listSerialPorts()
But nothing else is coming when I am tapping on the reader.
Also my smartTapRedemptionValue = 'Testing data'
I have tried using multiple libraries but Dot origin works on serial port, and I am not getting any results
